# How to indicate different voltage levels in schematic drawing

Tags: power, schematics, kicad

If I have a circuit where I will use different voltages for different parts, how is this best done?

This can be done with power symbols

[image: schematic example with power symbols]

or using local labels

[image: schematic example with local labels]

or global labels

[image: schematic example with global labels]

(the default size of global labels is insanely large, but resizing to 0.030 makes them usable).

Which one is preferred and why (just a matter of style or are there any functional differences)? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Absolutely, **absolutely** **ABSOLUTELY** the power symbols. Anyone who uses net labels (local or global) for power distribution should be fired.

Comment: Also, your error message isn't telling you it's not working, it's telling you that there is no power-source for your power connection (which is a side-benefit to power symbols,  the main reason is they significantly improve readability). You have to have a component where your power enters the net. This is (probably, I don't know kicad) a function of component pin definitions. In this case, you would edit pin one of the comparator, to set it as an output.

Comment: @Fake Name: I'm convinced by your first comment. Make it an answer and I'll accept it. I will create a new question for how to solve the error message.

Comment: Done! I also added a lot more commentary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Absolutely, **absolutely ABSOLUTELY** the power symbols.

Anyone who uses net labels (local or global) for power distribution should be fired.

The **entire purpose** of power symbols is to allow them to be quickly visually distinguished from local or global net labels, allowing the schematic to be more easily read and maintained.

I have dome a fairly significant amount of work troubleshooting and cleaning up schematics drawn completely with net labels, and it's a nightmare.

Furthermore, if you *have* to use net labels for some weird reason, **strictly** follow the local-global hierarchy. Many EDA packages let you set all net labels as global. If you do this, please die in a fire.
Only use global net labels when you have to. Nets should be local by default.

An even better option is to use an EDA package that enforces hierarchical schematic interconnects. This way, each schematic is represented as a "meta-component" on a higher-level schematic. Basically, every global net-label on each schematic is reflected as a pin on an higher-level drawing.

This makes the sheet-to-sheet interconnections immediately clear, and lets you trace out where, exactly, a net label routes.

Also, you should only **ever** have **one** global net label of every name on a sheet. If you have two devices that need to connect to that global net *wire them together with a schematic wire*. This is *vital* in situations where you are not the only person working on a schematic, and useful in all others, because it makes the schematic much more intuitively understandable.

---

Frankly, net labels are very, **very** overused as it is. The **only** situation where you should chose a net-label over actual schematic wires is when it improves readability. Unsuprisingly, this happens **very rarely**.

I see a lot of schematics these days that are basically a random assortment of chips tied together with net labels.

**This is a ABSOLUTELY HORRIBLE way to do schematics.**
If you have ever spent time tring to understand or modify a schematic *drawn by someone else*, which is based around net labels (particularly if it's complex), you will hate them with the fiery passion of a thousand suns.

**NET LABELS ARE ANTI-MAINTAINABILITY.

They are (rather literally) the GOTO statements of schematics.**

---

<sub>They connect somewhere else, and you have to manually find it (unless your EDA package lets you follow nets, but then, what if you're working on paper documents?). They may completely break out of the local document structure. They may have non-obvious effects, and mis-spelling things can cause errors which the DRC checking will not catch, because enforcing rules on net labels can be difficult.</sub>

---

One thing of note is that, (as Brian Carlton points out in a comment), that using net-labels to indicate the *function* of an *existing* wire is a very good thing to do.

> Net labels are only GOTO-like if they are connected by name. Otherwise they can just help debugging. For example DATA0 between a uC and SRAM on the same page.

Comment: Net labels are only GOTO-like if they are connected by name. Otherwise they can just help debugging. For example DATA0 between a uC and SRAM on the same page.

Comment: @Brian Carlton - Good point. Net-labels used in lieu of wires are destructive. Net labels used to indicate the *function* of a wire are good. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Sometimes I find it easier to read net labels than to follow wires.  To be sure, if the interconnects are almost in order, having them laid out graphically can make it visually clear where things deviate from the expected sequence, but if the interconnect pattern ends up being essentially random, adding a tangled morass of wires doesn't improve things.

Comment: @supercat - that only ever (marginally) true in situations where a wire would only go to two places. What if there is a net connected to three places? Or four? How would you ever know you have found every place a net-label connects to? I have had to maintain schematics drawn with net-labels, and it's a meticulous, mind-melting job.

Comment: I never got any good with the schematic-capture software used at my office; for a hobby project with a CPLD, SRAM, flash chip, and regulator, along with resistors and capacitors, my "schematic" was a spreadsheet with the netlist, which I then wrote a program to transform into a format the PC-board software could use.  My program produced a cross-reference listing, which made it easy to check that all connections were as expected.  By comparison, I find following many parallel lines on a schematic to be difficult.

Comment: @supercat - If you have that many parallel line on a schematic, it sounds like you should be using a bus.

Answer (score 3):

There are various legitimate ways to do this, despite the very noisy fanatical rantings of some.  Let's keep in mind the two fundamental purposes of a schematic: to define connections to the computer and to communicate the circuit to humans.  The software will usually enforce the first, but the second requires some thought and care.  Just like commenting code, good schematic clarity is important.

Any method that satisfies these constraints is valid.  I don't like your first example not because it uses power symbols, but because those power symbols look too much like connections or test points and therefore confuse.  I've seen power symbols that look like a T with the voltage shown above the T.  I think that would be a big improvement in your first schematic, after which I'd have no problem with it.

I ususally do similar to your second schematic.  I give power nets names based on their voltage, like "5V" or "3.3V", then use the built in facility in the software (Eagle in my case) to display the net's name wherever it is drawn to just end.  This labels it's function and makes it visually obvious the net is connected elsewhere.  I also usually make such stubs to power connections end upward when going to a consumer of that net.  Sometimes I might have the power net coming in from the left if that allows the schematic to be drawn more clearly.  Producers of the power net would have the stubs ending at the right to give the visual clue that the power is being "sent" elsewhere.  Signals should generally flow left to right in schematics, except feedback signals which should deliberately flow backwards (right to left).  Of course this isn't always possible or reasonable, but it's a good thing to strive for in the absence of reasons not to.

Again, I never manually draw the label by itself.  I always name the net, then use the feature in the software to show the net name.  That guarantees that two lines on the schematic with the same name are the same net.  It can also be useful to show the net name in the middle of a net line if that might help people understand its purpose better or more quickly.  As always, the driving consideration is clarity and to decrease how much someone has to "figure out" the schematic to understand the circuit.

One nit with your second schematic is that the labels aren't centered to the ends of the stubs.  That could lead to confusion when other things are nearby and looks a little sloppy.  It makes one wonder a little "Does he really mean that?".

A good example of what I'm talking about is the schematic for our ReadyBoard-02 at http://www.embedinc.com/products/ready02/qprot6.pdf.  The first page contains power supplies, and you can see several power nets being produced there and going off to other parts of the schematic at the right edge.  Note also that they are sorted from low to high voltage bottom to top as just another visual cue that might head off a misunderstanding, even if this is not obvious to the observer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The power symbols are the standard Kicad symbols, I cannot remember them having been different any time. The local labels were placed that way so the label anchor were at the end of the wire. Usually the label is placed over a wire in parallel (or 90 degrees to the wire), so for a real design it would have been better to let the wire "underline" the label. For these examples I wanted to have the schematic to be as similar as possible. But yes, unless there is lots of space around, it might cause confusion to have the labels hanging loose like that.

Comment: I resemble that noisy fanatical someone....

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppSvB.png) is how it is done in the Pulsonix software I use. The Signal Reference has the net assigned to it, and the net is defined as a power type.